# edit pdf document checkboxes and fields in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I would like to know how can I edit an existing PDF document in C#. The document is already created and has fields as the one on the image below:

[image: sample]

I want to know if there is a code which can check the desired checkbox or enter text at the lines. Please let me know.

I looked at iTextSharp but I don't know if that tool can help me achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with iTextSharp, BUT first you should find out more about the document.
 If the pdf contains an actual acroform form definition, filling it is fairly easy. There are many examples in the documentation and on the iText Web site.
 If it does not contain such a form definition, though, and the check boxes and text fields merely are some lines drawn somewhere, it gets a bit more difficult: you have to measure where to put your entries.
 Additionally you should find out whether the document is signed or encrypted which might limit what you are allowed to do with the document.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do it, but it requires external tools. I use ActivePDF library, it provides form filling routines and works quite well..

Comment: do you know any open source tool?

Comment: I've yet to find a suitable OSS toolkit that supports form filling of PDF's.

Comment: @Ed iText(Sharp) does support acroform forms fill-ins quite well and xfa support is getting better and better

Comment: @mkl that's why I love this web site. Learned something new every time. I periodically look for PDF libraries that are both OSS, and actually good. This one was below my radar for some reason..